# Does Application size affect startup speed and memory size

Tags: c#, performance, runtime

The Test program is a "HelloWorld" class.
 
Case 1: The program is compiled alone. Final dll compiled size is ~few bytes.
Case 2: there are unreferenced classes by HelloWorld main(). Final dll compiled size is 50 mb.

Questions:  Do both projects have the same :
1) memory footprint at runtime ? (does c# have to load entire dll in memory before it launches ?) 
2) start up time (time for program to load from disk into memory)? 
3) same compilation speed?

Before you say this is premature optimization. Know that no ide optimizes away dead / unreachable code. So i want to know if i should include it in "Release".

Comment: Of course not. we have a JIT. JIT compiles every function that you access at the first access. this means if you have an application with a huge initialization phase, it will get way more time than a simple application to load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I decided to come out of comments and write an answer,

1. LoadLibrary in C# is different than C/C++. in C#, meta data of all dlls are loaded at startup for type resolve and etc.. But the whole types are not Jitted until there is an access at runtime. (If you want to know more and dig into these questions, you can use OlyDBG and WinDBG and see memory footprints and load times)
2. In C#, methods are compiled at first access(of course there is RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod function for requesting JIT for a method, but it is a rare thing a developer might do). So, if you have an application that needs to initialize a lot of services at it startup, of course startup would be more time consuming rather than an application with the same size but with less JIT requirement at its startup.(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrcodegeneration/2007/09/15/to-ngen-or-not-to-ngen/
   Here is another article I found useful. it is about Anroid JIT but I think it sheds a light: https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/art-vs-dalvik-introducing-the-new-android-runtime-in-kit-kat)
3. Compilation Speed is some factor of input projects, level of optimization, etc. In C#, compiler compiles every code because we have reflection here and we can access all of codes that are in an assembly. (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a8024d/C-Sharp-program-compliation-steps/)